# How to use QSignalBlocker in Python?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, signals

I’m looking for either Python-specific documentation or--better yet--a sample snippet of Python code that shows how to use QSignalBlocker.  Will be grateful for anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QSignalBlocker class has a simple behavior: When it is set to a QObject  the emission of signals from the QObject is blocked, with the `unblock()` method the block is removed, with `reblock()` it is blocked again.

In the following example if the radiobutton is not checked then each time an item is selected from the QComboBox it will transmit the selected text to the QLabel through signals, if the radiobutton is checked then the signals will not be emitted so the QLabel will not show the text selected by the QComboBox:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        radiobutton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("block/unblock")
        self.m_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.m_combobox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.m_combobox.addItems(
            [
                "Monday",
                "Tuesday",
                "Wednesday",
                "Thursday",
                "Friday",
                "Saturday",
                "Sunday",
            ]
        )

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(radiobutton)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_label)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_combobox)

        self.m_blocker = QtCore.QSignalBlocker(self.m_combobox)
        self.m_blocker.unblock()
        self.m_combobox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.m_label.setText)
        radiobutton.toggled.connect(self.on_toggled)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(bool)
    def on_toggled(self, state):
        if state:
            self.m_blocker.reblock()
        else:
            self.m_blocker.unblock()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The same logic can be done with the blockSignals() method of the QObject's:

```py
class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        radiobutton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("block/unblock")
        self.m_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.m_combobox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.m_combobox.addItems(
            [
                "Monday",
                "Tuesday",
                "Wednesday",
                "Thursday",
                "Friday",
                "Saturday",
                "Sunday",
            ]
        )

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(radiobutton)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_label)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_combobox)

        radiobutton.toggled.connect(self.m_combobox.blockSignals)
        self.m_combobox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.m_label.setText)
```

Answer (score 6):

Looking at [the documation](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtCore/QSignalBlocker.html) you can see, that the QSignalBlocker provides a `__enter__` and a `__exit__` function. On `__enter__` the signals of the given object are blocked and on `__exit__` the blocked state is set to the previous state. You can see this, when you look at the original Qt-documentation for [QSignalBlocker](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-6.1/qsignalblocker.html) and see the `__enter__` function as the C++-constructor and the `__exit__` function as the C++-destructor.

To leverage these function you can use the [`with`-statement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) and block the signals effectively with this call:

```
with QSignalBlocker(self.double_spin_box) as blocker:
    self.double_spin_box.setValue(2.5)
```

This with-statement will translate this call to

```
blocker = QSignalBlocker(self.double_spin_box)
blocker.__enter__()
try:
    self.double_spin_box.setValue(2.5)
finally:
    blocker.__exit__()
```

Comment: Actually, the "as"-part of the with-statement would return None. Probably no one ever uses the blocker object, but I just fixed that kind-of incomplete context manager implementation. :)
The currently correct use would be "with QSignalBlocker(self.double_spin_box):"

Answer (score -1):

The above works, but I'm currently using an alternative mechanism that also works:

```
  self.blockSignals(True)
  self.field.clear()
  self.blockSignals(False)
```

Comment: This sort of negates the whole purpose of the signal blocker doesn't it? Per the docs the whole reason of the signal blocker is just convenience so that you don't have to block and then un-block signals.